# Windows8.1/Ubuntu Dual Boot from HDD/mSATA

Tags: ubuntu, ssd, multi-boot, windows-8.1, msata

I know that there are a lot of posts dealing with this issue; unfortunately, none of the proposed solutions worked for me.

here is my problem:
I would like to set a dual boot for Windows8.1 installed on my HDD 300Gb, and for Ubuntu on my new mSATA crucial 120Gb.
What i did first was entring the BIOS and changing the SATA controller to AHCI, disabling secure boot, putting the mSATA at the top of the boot order list, and choosing a UEFI boot mode.
Then, I rebooted from an Ubuntu live USB, and installed the ubuntu OS on the msata (Using the whole space, and formatted in ext4)

I then restarted, but the PC still boot up to Windows 8.1 and ignoring the mSATA...

Do you guys have an idea on this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose "Windows Boot Manager" as the boot option in your UEFI Boot manager which will be found in your firmware settings ("BIOS Screen").

UEFI firmwares come with a boot manager inbuilt, which you should be able to choose with a (F?) key on your keyboard, or from the firmware settings page. Windows makes it a point to aggressively keep its boot manager entry on top of the list. Ubuntu doesn't usually.